# When i click a button , i need to view the data which was present before to edit and update

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

Basically, I need to populate the data when I click edit. I've taken a `RecyclerView` to display the added data.

**Problem**: Whenever I click on edit action button I'm not able to view the data I added. When I click edit, it will be completely new fields to add. It's similar in adding new data.

Here's what I've tried.
#Program

**RecView Activity**

```
class RecView : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var addsBtn: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var recv: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var userList: ArrayList<UserData>
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
    lateinit var UN: EditText
    lateinit var PN: EditText
    lateinit var BD: EditText
    lateinit var AN: EditText
    lateinit var PD: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recview)
        userList = ArrayList()
        addsBtn = findViewById(R.id.addingBtn)
        recv = findViewById(R.id.mRecycler)
        myAdapter = MyAdapter(this, userList)
        recv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recv.adapter = myAdapter
        addsBtn.setOnClickListener { addInfo() }
    }


    private fun addInfo() {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adduser, null)
        val addDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        UN = v.findViewById(R.id.Title)
        PN = v.findViewById(R.id.Authname)
        BD = v.findViewById(R.id.Isbn)
        AN = v.findViewById(R.id.PublishedDate)
        PD = v.findViewById(R.id.Price)


        addDialog.setView(v)
        addDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog, _ ->
            val title = UN.text.toString()
            val authnumber = PN.text.toString()
            val isbn = BD.text.toString()
            val publisheddate = AN.text.toString()
            val price = PD.text.toString()

            userList.add(
                UserData(
                    "Title: $title", "Authname : $authnumber", "Isbn: $isbn", "Pubvlisheddate: $publisheddate", "Price: $price"
                )
            )

            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Adding User Information Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        addDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        addDialog.create()
        addDialog.show()
    }
}
```

**UserData model**

```
data class UserData (
    var Title:String,
    var Authname:String,
    var Isbn:String,
    var PublishedDate:String,
    var Price:String
)
```

**MyAdapter**

```
class MyAdapter(val c: Context, val userList: ArrayList<UserData>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {


    inner class UserViewHolder(val v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var title: TextView
        var authname: TextView
        var isbn: TextView
        var publisheddate: TextView
        var price: TextView

        var mMenus: ImageView

        init {
            title = v.findViewById(R.id.mTitle)
            authname = v.findViewById(R.id.mAuthname)
            isbn = v.findViewById(R.id.mIsbn)
            publisheddate = v.findViewById(R.id.mPublisheddate)
            price = v.findViewById(R.id.mPrice)
            mMenus = v.findViewById(R.id.mMenus)
            mMenus.setOnClickListener { popupMenus(it) }
        }

        private fun popupMenus(v: View) {
            val position = userList[adapterPosition]
            val popupMenus = PopupMenu(c, v)
            popupMenus.inflate(R.menu.menu)
            popupMenus.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                when (it.itemId) {
                    R.id.editText -> {
                        val v = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.adduser, null)
                        val title = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Title)
                        val authname = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Authname)
                        val isbn = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Isbn)
                        val publisheddate = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.PublishedDate)
                        val price = v.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Price)
                        AlertDialog.Builder(c)
                            .setView(v)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok") {
                                dialog,_->
                                position.Title=title.text.toString()
                                position.Authname=authname.text.toString()
                                position.Isbn=isbn.text.toString()
                                position.PublishedDate=publisheddate.text.toString()
                                position.Price=price.text.toString()
                                notifyDataSetChanged()
                                Toast.makeText(c, "User Information is Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                                dialog.dismiss()

                            }
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog,_ ->
                                dialog.dismiss()

                            }
                            .create()
                            .show()

                        true
                    }
                    R.id.delete -> {
                        /**set delete*/
                        AlertDialog.Builder(c)
                            .setTitle("Delete")
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_warning)
                            .setMessage("Are you sure delete this Information")
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes") { dialog,_->
                                userList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
                                notifyDataSetChanged()
                                Toast.makeText(c, "Deleted this Information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show()
                                dialog.dismiss()
                            }
                            .setNegativeButton("No") { dialog,_->
                                dialog.dismiss()
                            }
                            .create()
                            .show()

                        true
                    }
                    else -> true
                }

            }
            popupMenus.show()
            val popup = PopupMenu::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
            popup.isAccessible = true
            val menu = popup.get(popupMenus)
            menu.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setForceShowIcon", Boolean::class.java)
                .invoke(menu, true)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return UserViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val newList = userList[position]
        holder.title.text = newList.Title
        holder.authname.text = newList.Authname
        holder.isbn.text = newList.Isbn
        holder.publisheddate.text = newList.PublishedDate
        holder.price.text = newList.Price
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return userList.size
    }
}
```